# Magento : Backend event handle for customer save

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have tried searching the web for the event that gets fired when admin saves a customer information.

After getting tired of searching i have the option of adding the custom event in the core code but before moving into this action i would like to ask from experts if they know this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

It's the `customer_save_after` (or `customer_save_before`) dynamic event (model entity code `customer` + dynamic model event `_save_after`

If you only want to plug some code to this event in the Backend context : use the `adminhtml` XML tag in your `config.xml` when you register your new event (instead of `global` or `frontend`).

Answer (score 2):

```
<adminhtml>
   <events>
            <customer_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <my_customer_save_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Module_Namespace_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>yourMethod</method>
                    </my_customer_save_observer>
                </observers>
            </customer_save_before>
   </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
Class: Mage_Sales_Model_Observer
Method: customer_save_after
```